# segue destinationViewController not detecting destiation method

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a storyboard and using segues to navigate between views

I am using the following code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"thestring"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] function1:argument1:argument2];
        [[segue destinationViewController] function2:argument1:argument2];

    }
}
```

for some reason it is recognizing function1 as a member of the destination view controller but not function 2 , it displays me the current error:

```
no known instance method for selector 'function2'
```

function2 is assigned as a public function of the destination view controller (with a "-" before it) and it is also used inside the code of the destination view controller.

any reason why it does not detect it ?

Thanks

EDITED

the header declaration is as follows

```
-(void)function2:(NSString*)argument1:(NSString*)argument2;
```

Comment: Can you please post your actual method signatures (the declarations in your destination controller)?

Comment: Do you have it declared in your header & your header imported into your class?

Comment: @alladinian I added the method declaration

Comment: @Dustin , I have it declared in my header (and it s being used in the destination controller ) and it is imported into my class correctly (function1 is detected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cast to tell the compiler what class `destinationController` is actually an instance of.

Comment: Thank you Philip , I am new to iOS development , can you give me an example of a cast?

Comment: It's nothing to do with iOS, just fundamental C language programming.  Something like: `[(MyControllerClassName *)[segue destinationViewController] function2:argument1:argument2];`.

Comment: I am new with iOS development , and tried to search online and couldn t find an example , can you please give me a quick example ?

Comment: There was a sample in my previous comment.  Plug in your own class name and it should work.  (I can't **guess** what you called your view controller.)

Comment: actually it was a completley different issue , I simply forgot to include the destination class header file in the current destination file . I found that out when I tried to type MyControllerClass Name . thanks!